# Copying LookupId into all rows in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have two tables, one is `LookUpTable` where I have an id for `AttendanceType = Remote`. And I have another table where there is a column called `AttendanceType`.

I want to fetch the id from `LookupTable` and copy in all rows of another table into the column `AttendanceType` in SSIS package?

Comment: I am not sure you are really simplifying the question, but in this case it is better to use an update statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use merge join in ssis to join both the sources based on attendence type field and fetch required fields from both the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a MERGE JOIN query depending on your RDBMS.
You can also use the MERGE JOIN component and the SSIS OLE DB Destination. The data coming out of the sources must be sorted. To tell SSIS that the data is sorted, right-click on your source component. Click on show advanced editor then on input and output properties. Then pass the `IsSorted` box to True.
Then, you must indicate to SSIS which column acts as SortKey, ie on which column to sort the data.

Comment: Hi, I did the same, So I am fetching around 8000 rows from input 1 and only 1 row from input 2 which is my attendance id. I have 10 columns in input 1 and I am deselecting one column which is Attendance column and replacing that column with a single row selected from input 2 and naming that column AttendanceId. Howerever, the result in AttendanceId column is Null for all 8000 rows from input 1. Can you guide me in that? Thanks

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your package containing the dataflow ?